# Debian: Vlan interface does not come up

Tags: networking, debian

I have a vlan configured for my network interface. Since last reboot this does not come up anymore and if I try to start it manually, it fails

```
sudo ifup eno1.4000
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up eno1
ifup: could not bring up parent interface eno1
```

My os is debian 10 and this is my config:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  up route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.224 gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eno1

iface eno1 inet6 static
  address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::x
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1

auto eno1.4000
iface eno1.4000 inet static
  address 192.168.100.4
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  vlan-raw-device eno1
  mtu 1400a
```

bootlog shows

```
Aug 19 17:08:50 xxxx ifup[820]: ifup: failed to bring up eno1
Aug 19 17:08:50 xxxx ifup[820]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Aug 19 17:08:50 xxxx ifup[820]: ifup: failed to bring up eno1
Aug 19 17:08:50 xxxx ifup[820]: ifup: could not bring up parent interface eno1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifup: could not bring up parent interface eno1` suggests that there is some error when bringing up eno1. I suppose it's because your `up` command fails, so you could try using `post-up` instead or remove it, then run that command manually to check for possible issues.

By the way, you don't need to use `vlan-raw-device`, here is a note from [Debian network configuration reference](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Network_init_script_config):

> Note: If you name your VLAN interfaces ethX.YYY, then there is no need
>   to specify the vlan-raw-device, as the raw device can be retrieved
>   from the interface name.

Answer (score 0):

So this problem relates in a wrong configuration of the gateway - it's not so obvious as the primary interface somehow had an IP address and was reachable via ssh. However as the log shows als the primary interface did not came up properly.

Providing a correct gateway and rebooting the machine solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `auto ens18.263` to the interface file. That did prevent the interface to come up on reboot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/569132)

Comment: This is an answer.